# Is calling DynamoDBClient->Query obsolete now, given Iterators?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have been "turned off" from using DynamoDB due to the difficulty of querying.  Between having to code for `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` and other nasties, it didn't seem worth it.

However, in doing some research in [the AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_query) I came across the following code example:

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator('Query', array(
    'TableName'     => 'errors',
    'KeyConditions' => array(
        'id' => array(
            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                array('N' => '1201')
            ),
            'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
        )
    )
));

foreach ($iterator as $item) {
   ...
}
```

I created a test DynamoDB table with 20 tiny items and only 1 write and 1 read unit.  The idea was to ask for more than what was provisioned so as to intentionally create problems and see how they were handled.  The above code (slightly modified to match the hash key name) worked really well with no PHP Exceptions thrown.  This has my head spinning!  There are three questions that I could use some help with:

1) I received all 20 items in about 1 second.  Assuming "eventually consistent" reads, I expected this to take 10 seconds (at a minimum) with such a low read allocation.  Why am I getting 20 items so quickly with the Iterator method?

2) This [slide deck from re:Invent](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/using-dynamod-bwith-aws-sdk-for-php-tls305#btnPrevious) explains that the Iterator is handling all the possible DynamoDB Exceptions.  This would seem to make calling Query directly a thing of the past.  Do you agree that we should re-factor code to eliminate Query calls in favor of getIterator?

3) How does this change `try` `catch` logic?  Do we need to wrap the foreach loop or is that redundant?

Thank you for the input.

**EDIT**: Corrected the slideshare link - You are looking for slide #26 (best slide of the deck!)

Comment: You are allowed to burst your read and writes to dynamoDB for a short while (reading 20 items in one second and then do nothing for the rest of the time)

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're trying to do. In your example, you're still calling the Query operation directly, but you're yielding the result to an Iterator object. If you're always trying to get _all_ results, then sure, this makes sense.

Comment: @Guy - I can find nothing on AWS docs that documents what you are saying.  By any chance do you have a link that talks about burst ability?  And I am up to 80 small items now in a second (strongly consistent too!), repeated for 20 seconds (refreshing the page repeatedly).  No errors, no slowdown.  CLEARLY the 1 read per second must be some average over time, but what?

Comment: The overhead of measuring and throttling on the second level in the scale of DynamoDB is probably very high. If you notice, CloudWatch is working on a 1 minute or 5 minutes base. This is probably the range of burst you can get before throttling. Your tests are the best indicator for your use case.

Comment: @Guy - Thank you.  That answer is frustrating, but I do think you are likely right.  We geeks like certainty; there seems to be little here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the best source for information about the AWS SDK for PHP is the SDK's [User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/index.html). You should also check out the [AWS PHP Development Blog](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php) as well.

**Iterators** in the SDK do not replace the normal operation methods (e.g., `$client->query(...)`), but they can be a helpful abstraction if you have data that is likely to be paginated across multiple requests. Iterators also only emit a portion of the entire response — the data about the resource (e.g., DynamoDB items) — and ignore other meta data (e.g., table name, consumed throughput, etc.). They also use the same underlying objects as the operation methods (they are called `Command` objects) to perform the request. So doing `$client->query(...)` will use a single Command object, and doing `$client->getIterator('Query', ...)` (or, alternatively, `$client->getQueryIterator(...)`) will use 1 or more Command objects. See the [Iterators page in the User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-iterators.html) for more info.

The DynamoDB client in the PHP SDK is also configured to retry requests that fail due to exceeding provisioned throughput up to 11 times with very small delays that increase exponentially each time. We refer to this as **exponential backoff**. All of the service clients in the PHP SDK have some kind of exponential backoff configuration to smooth over things like throttling, bad network connections, and other intermittent errors so they don't bubble up as exceptions unnecessarily. However, once the maximum number of retries has been exceeded, the exception will bubble up. The backoff/retry logic applies to both operation methods like `->query()` and iterators. In your case, if you have a exception bubble up for exceeding your provisioned throughput, it means that you were really trying hard to exceed your throughput.

As far as your questions about **provisioned throughput, throttling, and bursting** go, this forum post from a member of the DynamoDB team should be helpful: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=427062. Essentially, there is a limited amount bursting allowed where you will not get throttled, but it is considered an implementation detail of the service, and not something you should consistently rely on.